# Putobject in AWS S3 from my android project in kotlin

Tags: android, amazon-web-services, post, amazon-s3, kotlin

I am amateur in both android studio and kotlin. However, I am designing an where I have post the new user data to AWS S3 for storage. I have done the same using `Putobject` but I am not able to know its been successful. Moreover, I want to know if I am doing it right. The code snippets are shown below.

```
val background= object :Thread() {
        override fun run() {
            try {
                try {
                    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(baseContext)
                    credentials = BasicAWSCredentials(AWSutils().KEY,AWSutils().SECRET)
                    s3Client = AmazonS3Client(credentials)
                    s3Client.putObject(AWSutils().bucket_name,AWSutils().KEY,new_parent.toString())
                } catch(e:AmazonServiceException) {
                    // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process
                    // it, so it returned an error response.
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(e:AmazonClientException) {
                    // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
                    // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }catch (e:Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
    background.start()
```

In the above scenario I'm trying to post my object new_parent. Since the syntax takes a string in the third argument, I've casted it to string.

Another clarification is that I have to run this a different thread because I get networkingonMainthread exception. Therefore, I have done the way you see the code above.

How do I know that the posting has been successful?

Any corrections and help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Checking if the posting the object has been successful can be done by printing the `objectContents` after `getObject`. Sample code snippet:

```
val background= object :Thread() {
        override fun run() {
            try {
                try {
                    AWSMobileClient.getInstance().initialize(baseContext)
                    credentials = BasicAWSCredentials(AWSutils().KEY,AWSutils().SECRET)
                    s3Client = AmazonS3Client(credentials)
                    val response = s3Client.getObject(AWSutils().bucket_name,"jsa3/NewParentData")
                    println("Checking the respose" + response.objectContent.toString())
                    Log.i(response.objectContent.toString(),"checking if response successful")
                    response.close()
                } catch(e:AmazonServiceException) {
                    // The call was transmitted successfully, but Amazon S3 couldn't process
                    // it, so it returned an error response.
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch(e:AmazonClientException) {
                    // Amazon S3 couldn't be contacted for a response, or the client
                    // couldn't parse the response from Amazon S3.
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }catch (e:Exception){
                e.printStackTrace()
            }
        }
    }
    background.start()
```

This should help.

Comment: Another way would be to use the getObjectMetadata method to get the meta data of the uploaded object. That will give you the same info i.e., that the object was successfully loaded, without having to fully download the object.